# MVC3 Azure app with table storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure-table-storage

Do you have any particular example for MVC3AzureApp which will display Data from the windows azure Table storage. and also CRUD Functionality for the table.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple Azure project with an MVC3 WebRole with basic CRUD functionality: [Download here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4SWnKVip0EGS1BMMUJzcGtST1E).

It's not pretty code and I use some bad practice, but this is just meant as an example.
Check "TableStorageController.cs" for all the table manipulation code.

Make sure you have Azure SDK 1.7, or just replace the references with older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get how to perform CRUD on Table Storage?
may be this can help you:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-web-site/4-worker-role-a/

And do you know how to perform Aggregate functions on windows Azure Storage Table too?